# FORM [method=POST] error - AMP pages prepared with C# Asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I am trying to create an AMP mobile web site with C# Web Form. I am receiving an error message when checking the AMP test page:

> Use of prohibited or invalid HTML tags. The attribute 'action' may not appear in tag 'FORM [method = POST]'

This is the form tag on my website:

```
<form method="post" action="./amp.aspx" id="ctl01">
```

How can i solve this problem? How can i change `action=` to `action-xhr=` in the web form?